# How to pass []byte to external exiftool via stdin?

Tags: go

I am trying to do in golang the  bash equivalent:

```
cat image.jpg | exiftool -author=some_auth - > updated_image.jpg
```

The exiftool **'-'** option makes it read from stdin, but say I have the image stored in a variable like 
    `var img []bytes //in golang`

I want stdin to contain the bytes from img and the system call to exiftool to read these from stdin, save the result (stdout) in another []byte - I am new to golang, how what do i approach this ?

I don't want to save to temp files on disk.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
out, err := os.Create("updated_image.jpg")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
cmd := exec.Command("exiftool", "-author=some_auth", "-")
cmd.Stdout = out
cmd.Stdin = bytes.NewReader(img)
err = cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
out.Close()
```

should work.

Note that I haven't tested the code.